# find_or_create from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of two Airport structs and need to check if each exists already, and, if not, create it. The unique key for each airport is its `:iata` code.

When created or found I need to add both `Airports` to `@trip`

```
airports = [departure_airport, arrival_airport]

airports.each do |a|
  Airport.where(iata: a.iata).first_or_create do |airport|
    unless airport.present?
      air = airport.create(a.to_h)
      @trip.airports << air
    else
      @trip.airports << airport
    end
  end
end
```

What am I missing? This creates the Airport but does not pass the variables from `a.to_h` with it.

Comment: I would add some debugging to check the value of `a.to_h` right before you call create just to check what is being passed. Also there's a separate gotcha in your code at the moment - the block passed to `first_or_create` only gets called if the object doesn't exist. So in the case where the airport already exists it won't currently be added to `@trip`

Comment: Indeed, can you propose a better Solution?

Comment: @TheMiniJohn so you meant your structs has no value ?

Comment: First of all you don't need `unless`...  Because _block_ will be called if there is a new one created, otherwise not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the handling of the scenario where the airport already exists you can rearrange the code to be like this:

```
airport = Airport.where(iata: a.iata).first_or_create(a.to_h)
# airport will now either be the first airport that was found,
# or the new one that was created depending on if one existed or not
# either way it can then be added to @trip
@trip.airports << airport
```

Comment: I'm don't think it's needed in order to do what the OP was asking for as the attributes for the new airport can be passed directly to `first_or_create`?

Comment: block is closure so.. you can do it inside it... But it is your choice.. :p

Comment: Hey mikej would you mind joining me on chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80433/find-or-create-array

Comment: do what inside? you mean the `@trip.airports << airport` ? if so, please see my comment on the question - the block only gets called if the airport *doesn't exist* so if we want to avoid repeating that line it has to be outside the block.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to test this: `unless airport.present?`, airport will be always present since `first_or_create` method returns a record or create new one.

Instead of `air = airport.create(a.to_h)` write: `airport.to_h = a.to_h`

---

Try this:

```
airports.each do |a|
    Airport.where(iata: a.iata).first_or_create do |airport|
        airport.to_h = a.to_h
        @trip.airports << airport
      end
    end
  end
```